# patch for files disappearing in the eclipse Navigator

Tags: eclipse, git, navigator, staging

The files in Navigator and editor tabs keeps disappearing in eclipse workbench.
Eclipse seems to be not interested in fixing the 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=458015

due to the fight between titans, does anyone know the root cause and a patch. Also, directions to build the appropriate plugin jar would be appreciated.

It is also affecting the git staging view so, it should be common problem.

[image]

**Reference**: 
**Eclipse 4.3 - kepler** is working very well with good performance, this bug is introduced from 4.4.
Here is the plugin versions and download link

- https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Kepler/SR2
- https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/kepler
- [**SourceLink:** https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/)

**EDIT: Steps to reproduce**

- Get any version of Eclipse-Windows-64-bit (i used J2ee) from Luna to Oxygen(latest)
- create a git project and add multiple files(any files).
- You should see these files in git-staging.
- Double-click on any file.
- You should see only 1 file visible and others will be invisible.


  **Steps for Editor tabs disappearing**
- Open multiple files.
- Move your mouse over the editor tabs.
- You should see tabs disappearing.

  [image]

ProjectExplorer has a weird issue (Same file shows up twice).[image: Project Explorer]

Comment: It's not a common problem as you can see in the bug from the few comments and the few votes. Why do you think there is no interest in fixing this bug which is still open and not as WONTFIX closed? Too bad you don't describe how to reproduce the bug and which Eclipse version and operating system you use.

Comment: I don't understand why would you expect anyone to know the root cause of your problem and have a patch when you specifically pointed out that it was still an open bug with Eclipse. But you could help them by updating any relevant Eclipse bug(s) if you have any new information to provide.